# Android NDK - how to get surface from native code

Tags: android, android-ndk, framebuffer, screen-capture

I want to develop a small binary tool for Android 10 which I'll call with adb shell from PC. This tool should capture requested part of the screen and return it back (on stdout or anything else). I don't really need any standard app in java, just that small bin tool.

Main issue for me is that I'm completely new in developing anything for Android.

So far I created ndk project in Android Studio and generated "mysc" bin app which I pushed in device:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("My capture command!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
C:\adb>adb shell data/local/tmp/mysc
My Capture Command!

C:\adb>
```

I don't need any native <-> java communication, just get current view of the screen and return only part of it. It would be almost the same functionality like screencap bin, but I don't need whole screen, just part of it. I've tried opening frame buffer like it is shown in old [screepcap source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a45746e/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp) but without any success.

I was looking in NDK samples and found "ANativeWindow" which looks like something I need, but I don't how to use it without connecting to app in java. The function which probably would give me surface is

```
ANativeWindow * ANativeWindow_fromSurface(
  JNIEnv *env,
  jobject surface
)
```

But it look like I need to call such function from java to catch env and surface. The solution is probably very easy but lack of knowledge about ndk it's very time consuming to do even some such simple like this...

For any help big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This task couldn't be applied to NDK, but AOSP should be used, because the following libraries are required: `libgui.so, libui.so` (for getting native surface), which are absent in the NDK.

So, you need to use AOSP build to make your binary and then push it to the target.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/nkh-lab/aosp-native-egl-intro) to Khronos EGL example adapted for AOSP native executable.